# object refrence not set to an instance of object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

For some reason i am getting an object refrence not set to an instance of an object.

```
  Protected Sub GridView6_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)     
      Dim date1 As Date     
      date1 = Date.Now      
      Dim date2 As Date      

      Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("label1"), Label)         
      date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)          
      Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)         
      Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays            
      If days <= 14 Then             
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red         
      ElseIf days > 14 And ts.Days < 30 Then 
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue         
      ElseIf days >= 30 Then 
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen         
    End If         
    End Sub
```

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 166:
> Line 167:        Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("label1"), Label)
> Line 168:        date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)
> Line 169:        Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)
> Line 170:        Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays
> ```
>
> Source File: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ChrisH\Desktop\AJAXEnabledWebSite18\Default.aspx.vb
>   Line: 168
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.] 
>   _Default.GridView6_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ChrisH\Desktop\AJAXEnabledWebSite18\Default.aspx.vb:168
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs
>   e) +108 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32
>   rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex,
>   DataControlRowType rowType,
>   DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean
>   dataBind, Object dataItem,
>   DataControlField[] fields,
>   TableRowCollection rows,
>   PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +1651
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +57 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +14 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data) +114 
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments,
>   DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>   +31  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   +142  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>   +73  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
>   +4  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   +82  System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +22 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +17 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +80  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171  System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +171  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is actually debugging the code...start it where ddate is created/set and step through. That appears to be your 'null reference' error that isn't rearing its head until the next line. See if it is actually pulling a value from the CType() function.

Comment: You should be able to put a breakpoint on line 168 and see that (most likely) ddate or ddate.Text is null.  The reason will depend on the context.  Is the label really there?  Do you have the right name?

Comment: Pro-tip: name your controls. You won't like it when you're trying to remember if the date is in label23 or label17.

Comment: i changed the name to duedate, and found that date2 is 12:00 am even though i am not using time. and also ddate is nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saying that you do not have a control called "label1" in the row. This is very likely correct since the row can only have `Cells`. You need to access the specific cell by its column on a zero-based index:

```
Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("label1"), Label)
```

Keep in mind to change the `(2)` above to match the column number.

**Edit:** It appears that you haven't made any checks to make sure that you're looking at a DataRow vs a HeaderRow or FooterRow. Here is a snippet:

```
Protected Sub GridView6_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' CHECK THE ROW TYPE HERE. ONLY EXECUTE ON DataRow     
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim date1 As Date     
        date1 = Date.Now      
        Dim date2 As Date      

        Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("label1"), Label)         
        date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)          
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)         
        Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays            
        If days <= 14 Then             
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red         
        ElseIf days > 14 And ts.Days < 30 Then 
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue         
        ElseIf days >= 30 Then 
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen         
        End If         
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - The result is because the label doesn't exist with the name you've indicated in the places you're telling it to search. Keep in mind that `FindControl` is a very specific method and is not recursive at all. It will only look in the `ControlCollection` of the object you call it on. When you're debugging, you might want to go into your "immediate" window and make this call on all of the columns to make sure you have the right column index.

Comment: i did it for every column an all returned nothing

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - then I would say you don't have any controls named `label1` defined in your templates, or at least defined in the template you're currently accessing. Keep in mind, it doesn't appear that you've filtered out the header row. I'll provide an edit.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - snippet added.

Comment: i hope it is the whole header thing, because i am 98% sure that i have a control named label1 in the template i am accessing.

Answer (score 3):

`ddate` is `null`, because there is no `label1`.

Comment: wait ddate is null but date2 is a time which makes no sense